# CSS using grid to vertically center not working

Tags: css, css-grid

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-currying-h7c3r?file=/styles.css

Been googling for 30 minutes, nothing is working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css)

Comment: `height: 100vh` to body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `min-height:100vh` to the `body` element.

By default, the `body`'s height is collapsing to be the height of it's content.